# display <nav> if user is connected with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I use JWT to authenticate, I apply a condition to display the  that contains all menus for loggued user.

```
<app-nav *ngIf="currentUser"></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem is that after login screen app redirect to dashboard, that is ok, but without . I have to refresh page so that it appears.

I get currentUser from my App component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public loading = false;
  public currentUser: User;

  constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService) {
    this.currentUser = auth.currentUser();
    }
}
```

And in authservice:

```
public currentUser(): User {
    const json = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN);
    const decoded = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(json);
    if (decoded) {
      return decoded.sub;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

All my pages are in

Why is it happening, and what should I do to avoid it ?

EDIT: @Nunicorn I have followed your code, but I still can't  make it work, here is an update of my code:

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentUser: User;

  constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.currentUser$.subscribe((user: User) => {
      console.log(user.id);
      this.currentUser = user;
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-nav *ngIf="currentUser"></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    onSubmit() {
    this.auth.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

AuthenticationService:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('https://api.kz-api.test/auth/login', {email: email, password: password}, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          if (res && res.token) {
            this.setToken(res.token);
            this.currentUser();
            this.toastr.success('Welcome');
          }
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('login', []))
      );
  }

public currentUser(): User {
    const json = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN);
    const decoded = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(json);
    if (decoded) {
      this.currentUser$.next(decoded.sub);
      return decoded.sub;
    }
    return null;
  a}
```

The issue is still the same, after login, the navbar doesn't appear, I have to refresh browser so that it appears

Comment: You need more context to this question. Where does `currentUser` come from? Is it retrieved from a service? Is it just in the `app-nav` component? I assume your login screen is in `router-outlet`, so how are you communicating to your app-nav`?

Comment: Yes you are right, I will update my question

Comment: updated. I'm not sure about the answer to the question: how are you communicating to your app-nav. I thinks I'm not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so your problem is you are setting `currentUser` in the constructor for your app component. The constructor will only get called once, on initialisation, so it doesn't know about any changes to the auth user from `AuthenticationService` after you login. Once you refresh, it **will** call the constructor again, and thus, show your nav bar.

Instead, use an observable in your `authservice` to publish changes to any subscribers, which can include your nav bar.

i.e (AuthService)

```
currentUser$: Subject<User> = new Subject<User>();

public logInUser(): User {
    const json = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN);
    const decoded = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(json);
    if (decoded) {
       this.currentUser$.next(decoded.sub);
    }
}
```

This will mean **any** component that has the Auth service injected can then subscribe to that subject. So your AppComponent can become:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public loading = false;
    public currentUser: User;

    constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.auth.currentUser$.subscribe((user: User) => {
               this.currentUser = user;
         }
    }
}
```

You will note I put the `currentUser$` subject as a local variable in AuthService, rather than returning it from the `currentUser()` function. The reason for this is, by using this method, you can also handle log out, without changing anything in your app component.

e.g

```
logOutUser() {
    this.currentUser$.next(undefined);
    // + whatever other logout stuff you need to do
}
```

App component (and any other subscribers) can pick up that `currentUser$` is now `undefined`, and your nav bar will hide again.

**Simple Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hy8aq7

Comment: I'm testing it... can you tell me why the $ at the end of the var, and $net ?

Comment: ah, ok, it s a convention telling that it is an observable. but $next ???

Comment: `$` is a convention for naming observables.  `.next(<value>)` tells the observable what its next value is, and thus, what subscribers will receive. Some observables maintain a history of their values, hence the `.next()`

Comment: You don't have to use `$`, but its a god way of separating observables from normal variables. Also, there is no `$next`, that was just a typo...

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Edited to include a very simple Stackblitz version.

Comment: still can't do it. the problem is still the same you pointed at first: the app component is called only once, and after login, it is not called again, only when refreshing the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173282/discussion-between-nunicorn-and-juliatzin-del-toro).

Comment: I could make it. I just replaced <app-nav *ngIf="currentUser"></app-nav> with <app-nav *ngIf="auth.getCurrentUser()"></app-nav>